# Probability/ eggs in boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have n boxes and n eggs, which were hidden randomly in these boxes. The probabilty, that no egg is in the right box, is 
$$ \sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!} $$

How can I get to this formula?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: Such permutations are called *derangements*, and is a typical application of inclusion-exclusion principle. You can find an extensive list of Q&A's related to this in this community.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will look for that:)

Comment: Maybe you can explain. why the index of the sum starts at 2?